# Using line count as a counter to break a while loop in Bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, conditional-statements

Is it possible to use a line count to break a while loop in bash?

I have the following code but it doesn't break and infinitely runs:

```
wc -l Database.faa > counter
perl -p -e 's/ /\t/g' counter | cut -f6 > temp; mv temp counter

while
     ($counter > '0')
do

    # some commands

    wc -l Database.faa > counter
    perl -p -e 's/ /\t/g' counter | cut -f6 > temp; mv temp counter

done
```

My program reduces Database.faa with each run but when Database.faa is empty it continues to run. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: please indent a little bit and show us your research effort. there are too many problems in such a small snippet.

Comment: Is this what you mean, HuStmpHrrr? :)

Answer (score 2):

In your conditional `$counter` does not look at a file `counter` which is seemingly what you're trying to use in the condition.  Also, `(` isn't a traditional way to test values, though you can use the exit code of the subshell you're creating.  You're probably more interested in `[` which is the same as the `test` command.  Finally, for this part, when using `test` `>` is not a comparison operator, it's a redirection operator.  `man test` shows the comparison you can do, and for int comparisons you'd use `-gt` instead.  So putting that together we can do your loop like

```
counter=$(wc -l Database.faa | cut -f1 -d" ")
while [ $counter -gt 0 ]; do
     # some commands
     counter=$(wc -l Database.faa | cut -f1 -d" ")
done
```

or, you could just test if the file is empty like

```
while [ -s Database.faa ]; do
    # some commands
done
```

Comment: Use `$(wc -l < Database.faa)` to avoid the call to `cut`.

Comment: Thank you both for this. It was so helpful! :)